# Show test description of NUnit-tests in XML-output file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, output, nunit

After running my unit tests with Resharper I create an XML-output-file.

My description attribute `[Description("my description")]` doesn't show any description of each test in the XML-file.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Looks as if ReSharper does not look at "Description" attribute at all https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-56087.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this
github ticket](https://github.com/spekt/nunit.testlogger/issues/69#issuecomment-846443647), it is possible to do it on the command line:

```
dotnet test path/to/your/project.csproj --logger:nunit;LogFileName=TestResults.xml -- NUnit.ShowInternalProperties=true
```

This only worked for me after adding the NUnitXml.TestLogger Package to my project.